# Custom ListView Adapter isn't working with List<List<String>> instead of String[]

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a listView inside a fragment.

Im getting some json from the net and passing it into a `List<List<String>>`.

For some reason the list doesnt work.. there's no crash and there's nothing suspicious in the logcat..

it just doesnt show anything in the ListView.

Adapter's call (From the fragment):

```
setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(getActivity(), items));
```

This is my adapter's code:

package com.example.free;
import java.util.List;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    public List<List<String>> items;
    //private final static String[] a={"s"};

    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, List<List<String>> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ProgressBar loader = (ProgressBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.loader);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemimgae);
        TextView views = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.views);
        TextView likes=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
        TextView upvote=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.upvote);
        TextView downvote=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.downvote);
        TextView desc=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        TextView pub =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pub);
        TextView idnum =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idnum);

        Log.e("title",items.get(1).get(1));

        title.setText("      "+items.get(1).get(position));
        views.setText(items.get(6).get(position));
        likes.setText(items.get(7).get(position));
        upvote.setText(items.get(8).get(position));
        downvote.setText(items.get(9).get(position));
        desc.setText(items.get(4).get(position));
        pub.setText(items.get(5).get(position));
        idnum.setText(items.get(0).get(position));


        return rowView;
    }
}
```

`items` comes full.. I checked it, but for some reason the data doesnt get to the adapter..

Whats wrong here?

**EDIT**:

```
10-12 14:23:02.880: W/dalvikvm(23285): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4107b930)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at com.example.free.MobileArrayAdapter.getView(MobileArrayAdapter.java:49)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2438)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
10-12 14:23:02.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23285):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT #2:**

```
{List of lists:
{Titles list(Strings):bla,bla,bla},
{desc list(Strings): bla, bla,bla},
{another list(Strings): bla, bla,bla},
}
```

here's a pic

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJuoN.png)

Comment: @JaydipsinhZala: As is noted in the question, the OP is using fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are chaining to the wrong constructor, and your class is mis-declared.

Change:

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
```

to:

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List<String>>
```

And change:

```
super(context, R.layout.list_item);
```

to:

```
super(context, R.layout.list_item, 0, items);
```

You can then dump your own `items` data member and adjust `getView()` accordingly.

What is happening is that `ArrayAdapter` knows nothing of your `List<String>`, and so therefore it will return `getCount()` of 0.

The `0` in the `super()` call here is safe because you are not chaining to the superclass, electing to handle everything in `getView()` yourself.

However, that points out issues in your `getView()` implementation:

- **Please recycle your rows**, by using `convertView` if it is not `null`
- Consider using `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()` instead of always creating a new one, in case the activity either caches a `LayoutInflater` or supplies you with a specialized one
- `"      "+items.get(1).get(position)` is probably not a good idea, compared to designing your row layout such that this `TextView` is positioned where you want it to be
- Given how many widgets are in your row, please consider using the `ViewHolder` pattern to cache those `findViewById()` calls

Comment: thanks! but it caused some errors that crash the app. Ive added the logcat to the question.

Comment: @idk: See Vickyexpert's answer -- you probably have bugs in your `getView()` implementation.

Comment: No, I checked it. `title.setText("      "+items.get(1).get(position));` is supposed to be like that.

Comment: @idk: Then you are not going to be able to build your list with that data. The `List` used by `ArrayAdapter` has to be the list of **rows**. According to you, it is not the list of rows. Otherwise, `items.get(1)` would always be returning the first row.

Comment: But its a List of Lists of Strings.. Cant I use it as it is? all the List<String>'s inside the big List<List<String>> are the same size..

Comment: @idk: Then your statement where "is supposed to be like that" is incorrect, and your comment on Vickyexpert's answer is incorrect. As I said in my answer, "you can then dump your own `items` data member and adjust `getView()` accordingly". Change `items.get(1).get(position)` to `getItem(position).get(1)` (which is equivalent to what Vickyexpert suggested).

Comment: ok mate, sorry for being such a noob, but let me understand something: How is `items.get(position).get(1)` supposed to work if the `List<List<String>>` is formed like that: (GO TO Question EDIT #2)

Comment: I dont understand, what do you mean by dumping `items`?

Comment: @idk: Then we are back to "Then you are not going to be able to build your list with that data. The List used by ArrayAdapter has to be the list of rows. According to you, it is not the list of rows."

Comment: How can I solve this then? And what list of rows? its a list of lists of strings.. Bottomline: I need to make a list out of `List<List<String>>`. how can I do that?

Comment: @idk: "How can I solve this then?" -- replace `List<List<String>>` with `List<SomeModelClassThatYouWriteThatWillHelpYouStopGettingConfusedByNestedLists>`. Populate your instances of `SomeModelClassThatYouWriteThatWillHelpYouStopGettingConfusedByNestedLists` from the requisite strings. Make your `ArrayAdapter` then be an `ArrayAdapter<SomeModelClassThatYouWriteThatWillHelpYouStopGettingConfusedByNestedLists>`, and adjust `getView()` accordingly.

Comment: @idk: "And what list of rows?" -- a `ListView` is a list of rows. Your `ListAdapter` also needs to think in terms of rows. In particular, an `ArrayAdapter` needs to have the "array" (e.g., `List`) be a list of model data, where each element in the list *directly* maps to a row in the `ListView`. You are also welcome to abandon `ArrayAdapter` and create your own `BaseAdapter` subclass that deals with your current data structure, if you so choose.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code if it is working

I think Your Items list has no more data which you rae going to access

Check Below code:

```
    title.setText("      "+items.get(position).get(0));
    views.setText(items.get(position).get(1));
    likes.setText(items.get(position).get(2));
    upvote.setText(items.get(position).get(3));
    downvote.setText(items.get(position).get(4));
    desc.setText(items.get(position).get(5));
    pub.setText(items.get(position).get(6));
    idnum.setText(items.get(position).get(7));
```

May be list size is small and returns null so check this one.

Comment: I checked it. This is not the problem.